# Could not load jvm.dll while calling a java mysql udf

Tags: java, mysql, triggers, udf

In mysql udf it says could not load jvm.dll when i am trying to call java method using javaudflauncher.dll?

I want to call a java method from Mysql on Mysql trigger. I used the sample example provided by https://dejard.bitbucket.io
I have followed the steps as documented
- Setup the enviromental variable for Java & Mysql
- Copied the dll, jar and class files to the plugin directory
- Created the Function.
Till here it works fine. But when I try to call the function it gives me  the below error
    "`ERROR 1123 (HY000): Can't initialize function 'call_java_method'; Could not load jvm.dll`"

If anyone can help me out where I am going wrong.